# R append last row to a data frame

Tags: r, filter, append

I have a data frame (df) that shares a key column ($Name) with a list of data frames:

```
head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 3 ##truncating to show first 2 rows only
  Name      var1  var2
 <chr>      <chr> <chr>
1 Tom Marks LAX   ORD
2 Bob Sells MIA   CHI
```

I have a list of data frames that contains historical data for each person contained in df$Name.

```
head(employees$'Tom Marks')
Name      date       var3
Tom Marks 2017-01-01 250
Tom Marks 2017-01-02 457

head(employees$'Bob Sells')
Name      date       var3
Bob Sells 2017-01-01 385
Bob Sells 2017-01-02 273
```

I would like to append the value in *var3* from *employees* list to the df by the most recent date (which is always the last row in an *employees* list).  For example, the output, after matching *Tom Marks* from df$Name to employees$'Tom Marks' would look like this:

```
head(df)
  Name      var1  var2  var3
 <chr>      <chr> <chr> <num>
1 Tom Marks LAX   ORD   457
2 Bob Sells MIA   CHI   273
```

I have spent a decent amount of time researching filtering joins, mutating joins, bind_rows, reduce() functions but have been unsuccessful in accomplishing what is probably an easy task for a decent programmer.  I'm hoping someone out there can put me out of my misery and provide some better direction or better yet, an answer!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're always after the last row, you can use `tail` to get it:

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(
  df, 
  map_df(employees, ~ tail(.x, 1))  
)
```

Comment: Here I was trying mutating and filtering joins when this simple method was all it was took. I have to keep learning tidyverse; it's a great library! This was very helpful and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This solution relies on the fact that your data arranged as you said they were, but you can easily arrange the list by `date` if they were not so.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% left_join(
  df_list$employees %>% 
    bind_rows() %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(var3), last))

#        Name var1 var2 var3
# 1 Tom Marks  LAX  ORD  457
# 2 Bob Sells  MIA  CHI  273
```

---

Data

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Tom Marks", "Bob Sells"),
                 var1 = c("LAX", "MIA"),
                 var2 = c("ORD", "CHI"))

df_list <- list(employees = list(
  `Tom Marks` = data.frame(Name = "Tom Marks",
                           date = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02"),
                           var3 = c(250, 457)),
  `Bob Sells` = data.frame(Name = "Bob Sells",
                           date = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02"),
                           var3 = c(385, 273))
))
```

Comment: While Melissa Key's solution worked well, I wanted to understand your code. At: summarise_at(vars(var3), by "vars" are you calling var1 and var2 from df?